# Using Windows Authentication based on user group assigned

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using ASP.NET webforms application with windows authentication. I want to allow authentication based on the user group assigned to the user. Can this be done with the web.config change only ?

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>

<authorization>
  <allow roles="BUILTIN\GroupAUsers"/> 
  <deny users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

The above similar change is denying every users even though user is in the usergroup such as "BUILTIN\GroupAUsers". How can be allow this for user in given usergroup only ?

Comment: Which version of IIS? Where are you adding the `<authorization>` element? If >= IIS7 make sure you are adding it to the `system.webServer/security` node.

Comment: I'm using IIS 10, currently ut is under <system.web> element

Comment: Did adding it to system.webServer change anything?

Comment: that also did not work for some reason.